# Viber bot для чайников

Tags: viber

Приветствую!
Задача такая.
Есть приложение на Access, необходимо по некоторому набору событий в Access отправлять сообщения подписчикам бота Viber.
Со стороной Access и VBA я разберусь, интересует остальная часть процесса, поскольку с сетями и ботами я дела не имел.
Аккаунт бота Vibe уже зарегистрирован.

Как я себе представляю, мне обязательно нужен сервер с Python/PHP.
Там я пишу скрипт, обрабатывающий входящие запросы и формирующий сообщение в сторону бота.
Входящие запросы могут быть в формате URL с параметрами. Во входящем запросе передавать буду, например, текст сообщения и id чата/собеседника.

Буду благодарен любой информации, которая быстро поможет мне въехать в технологию и реализовать задачу.
Ссылки и комментарии для dummies - пишите всё даже самое очевидное для Вас, так как я ВООБЩЕ ни разу не влезал в веб.

Если по пунктам, то интересует:
1. Как настроить обработку входящих сообщений на сервер, интересен как PHP, так и Python
2. Как правильно использовать API, чтобы всё работало

Comment: "Как скачать интернет?" - настолько троллинг что всерьез? xD

Comment: Просто второй вопрос настолько огненный, что во избежание бурления масс, решил немного скрасить юмором))

Comment: Зачет. Но все же - *"Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов."*